# Turn off Nginx Gzip for a specific query string (used with nodejs)

Tags: node.js, nginx, gzip

I'm using nginx to gzip static files & json responses from a nodejs server.

For one specific request (with a query string like `"?fn=foo"`), I need to send a non-gzip json response.

I've tried to achieve this with nginx location module, based on a regex on the query string, but the query string is not in the URI used to match location by nginx
I've tried to put a `if ($arg_fn = "foo") {gzip off;}` in my main location route, but it fails with a 404 instead.

Any idea?
Is it possible to achieve this with nginx? or is there a way to tell from nodejs to nginx not to gzip this response?

My nginx conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
    proxy_temp_path /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    upstream upstream {
      server 127.0.0.1:8887;
      server 127.0.0.1:8888;
      keepalive 64;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  _;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/zellno-ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/zellno-key.pem;


        location / {
            if ($arg_fn = "comp") {
                gzip off;
            }

            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://upstream/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to move the proxy settings inside the `location /` instead of being outside in the server block scope ?

Comment: I just dit, but it changed nothing. It works great without the if, but doesn't with the if. The only thing I can do is disable gzip for all application/json. But I would like to keep it and disable only for this request (it's a request with multi part response, which is not possible with gzip)

Comment: ok so the other way around, did you try moving the `if` outside the location block ?

Comment: it's not allowed, I can't start nginx if the if statement is outside the location block

Comment: according to the docs it can exist in the server scope, please check the error log and see what's making it not start

Comment: Apparently, the if statement is allowed outside the location block, but not outside the server block.
But the gzip is not allowed in the server block.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip , i guess if it's inside an `if` it needs to be inside a location, try putting a return statement to make sure if you enter that `if` or not, ill show an example in my answer

Comment: you mean this: "http, server, location, if in location"? the gzip is allowed in server block but only if in a location block?

Comment: I am not sure, the way I understood it is its allowed in `http`,`server`,`location` and also allowed inside an `if` only if it's inside a location block

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I try, nginx tells me: "gzip" directive is not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you said `$args_fn` with an "s", while it should be `$arg_fn` in singular form, try that and tell me how it goes.

**EDIT**:
Try this to make sure that you enter the if block

```
location / {
    if ($arg_fn = "comp") {
        return 444;
        #gzip off;
    }
}
```

If it returns the error code then the `if` is working but not the gzip, if it doesn't work then we need to fix the `if` first

Comment: can you share the whole config file

Comment: The 444 status code was not working, but with a 503 it works.
So the if seems to work. But nginx documentation says we should not use the if statement because of errors issued, so I guess it's one of the cases.